# How to add dynamic key and value(s) to a Dictionary

Tags: python

When the Dictionary is already initialized with keys we can easily add new values to it like:

```
newcolor = "green"
cardict = {
  "brand": "Ford",
  "electric": False,
  "year": 2201,
  "colors": ["red", "white", "blue"]
}

cardict["colors"].append(newcolor)

print(cardict)
```

but what if I need to add a new set of value and key dynamically by code:

```
color1 = "red"
cardict = {
  "brand": "Ford",
  "electric": False,
  "year": 2201
}
cardict["colors"].append(color1)

print(cardict)
```

As you can see when I try to add the new key (in type of array) like `cardict["colors"].append(color1)` I am getting this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 23, in <module>
    cardict["colors"].append(color1)
KeyError: 'colors'

[Program exited with exit code 1]
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Why don't you create the dictionary with an empty `colors` element?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check if the dictionary already has the key or not:

```
if "colors" in cardict:
    cardict["colors"].append(color1)
else:
    cardict["colors"] = [color1]
```

You could also use a `defaultdict`.

```
from collections import defaultdict

cardict = defaultdict(list, {
  "brand": "Ford",
  "electric": False,
  "year": 2201,
  "colors": ["red", "white", "blue"]
})
color1 = "red"
cardict["colors"].append(color1)
```

`defaultdict(list)` will automatically create a missing element as an empty list.

Answer (score 1):

```
color1 = "red"
cardict = {
  "brand": "Ford",
  "electric": False,
  "year": 2201
}

cardict.setdefault("colors",[]).append(color1)

print(cardict) # {'brand': 'Ford', 'electric': False, 'year': 2201, 'colors': ['red']}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to add the key first, mapped to an empty list, *then* append to the list.

```
if "colors" not in cardict:
    cardict["colors"] = []
cardict["colors"].append(color1)
```

The `setdefault` method can make this simpler, though at the cost of building the default value even when it won't be needed.

```
# Always creates a new list instance to pass to setdefault,
# even when setdefault will ignore it
cardict.setdefault("colors", []).append(color1)
```

A `defaultdict` makes this a little more efficient if you know in advance that a new key will need a list value, both visually by reducing the syntax and in performance, only calling `list` when needed to produce an empty list:

```
cardict = defaultdict(list, {
  "brand": "Ford",
  "electric": False,
  "year": 2201
})

# Only calls list to make a new empty list
# if "colors" is a new key.
cardict["colors"].append(color1)
```

---

Note that *all* new keys in the default dict will produce a list value, not just `"colors"`. There's no way to specify per-key factories for missing values, *unless* you define your own subclass of `defaultdict` that overrides its `__missing__` method to examine the new key in more detail before deciding what to do with it. This is beyond the scope of this answer, though.